# Unable to Write the Step Defination Getting Error?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am Trying to Automate the Rest API Authentication however i have Written the Feature File but in Step definition i am getting errors

My Code is 
Feature File:

```
 Feature: Authentication with Bearer Token

    Scenario: Verify Parameter of Get
        Given I perform GET operation for "/posts"
        Then I should see verify GET Parameter

    @smoke
    Scenario: Verify GET Operation with bearer Authentication Token
        Given I perform authentication operation for "/auth/login" with body
            | userName | Password |
            | Test | abc@123  |
        Given I perform GET operation for "/post"
        And User enters <userName> and <Password> Then Message displayed Login Successfully
```

**Here is the Runner**

```
package Runner;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="classpath:API Features/IdentityAPI",glue="StepDefination",plugin="html:target/test-report")
public class TestRunner {

}
```

Comment: You need to edit your question and post the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Use scenario outline as shown below, if still not working please share the error message

```
@smoke
    Scenario Outline: Verify GET Operation with bearer Authentication Token
        Given I perform authentication operation for "/auth/login" with body

        Given I perform GET operation for "/post"
        And User enters <userName> and <Password> Then Message displayed Login Successfully
Examples:
 | userName | Password |
            | Test | abc@123  |
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help...However i have tried that one but i am unable execute the Step Definition could you please share one Example if have any?I have Tried the Below Step Definations

public class GETPostsSteps {


    public static ResponseOptions<Response> response;

Comment: @Given("^I perform GET operation for \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void iPerformGETOperationFor(String url) throws Throwable {
        response = RestAssuredExtension.GetOpsWithToken(url, response.getBody().jsonPath().get("access_token"));
    }

Comment: @Given("^I perform authentication operation for \"([^\"]*)\" with body$")
    public void iPerformAuthenticationOperationForWithBody(String url, DataTable table) throws Throwable {

        var data = table.raw();

        HashMap<String, String> body = new HashMap<>();
        body.put("email", data.get(1).get(0));
        body.put("password", data.get(1).get(1));
        response = RestAssuredExtension.PostOpsWithBody(url, body);
    }
}